# Function in C returns previous value after been called twice

Tags: c, function

So I wrote this function in C that asking the user to put either "N" or "Y" as their response:

```
int loop_yn(){ //function that keeps asking player for prompt if entry (y/n) is invalid
            //returns either 0 or 1; 0 for "No" and 1 for "Yes"
char player[1024];

char f = player[0];
while(f!= 'Y' && f!='N' && f!='n'&& f!='y') {
    printf("Error: please enter Y or N: ");
    scanf("%s", &player);
    f = player[0];
}

if (f == 'n' || f == 'N'){
    return 0;
}
else {
    return 1;
```

}
}

I'm using this function twice in my main(), on the first part it worked as expected, however, when it runs to where I call this function again, the function passes without asking for input, and it returns the same result as it was called firsted time. what is wrong with my function here?

Comment: You should initialize `char player[1024];`.

Comment: `char player[1024] = {0};`

Comment: You should get rid of the oversized buffer (that can never be large enough to be secure), and instead just declare the variable as `char f = '?';` and use `scanf(" %c", &f);`

Comment: Mosaic J, what do you think is the value of `player[0]` when `char f = player[0];` is called?  - the line before the `while` loop.

Comment: Post a [mcve]. that show the 2 calls and stuff in between.

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest another "cleaner take" on that function and its purpose...

where we might need less variables

```
int loop_yn(void){

    char player;

    while(1){
        printf("Please enter yes or no (y/n) : ");
        if(scanf(" %c", &player) != 1){
            return 0;
        }
        else if(player == 'y' || player == 'Y'){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(player == 'n' || player == 'N'){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the relevant portion of code is here:

```
char player[1024];

char f = player[0];
while(f!= 'Y' && f!='N' && f!='n'&& f!='y')...
```

What you do here is declare a char array of 1024 bytes, withOUT initializing it. That means that your array is holding whatever happened to be there in memory at the moment. When you define `char f` to be the first value in your array, the value of `f` is undefined; it is garbage data. Don't compare garbage data in your while loop in case whatever that garbage happens to be is relevant to your condition. This can be fixed by ensuring that user input is stored in `f` before checking its value. This could be done with a `do...while` loop.

On another note, the char array is unnecessary. karimkohel does a good job of demonstrating how and why.

As for exactly why you see this behavior of it failing your expectations second-time round, the likeliest explanation is probably that the value of `f` that passed the `while` loop is still hanging out on your stack and getting put in f again the second time.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function definition shall have the following declaration

```
int loop_yn( void )
{
    //... 
}
```

That is its list pf parameter declarations shall contain `void`.

There is no great sense to declare such a large character array

```
char player[1024];
```

The function expects that the user will enter only one character and press Enter.

As the array was not initialized then the object `f` initially has indeterminate value

```
char f = player[0];
```

As a result the following loop has undefined behavior.

In this call of `scanf` there is specified an incorrect argument

```
scanf("%s", &player);
```

There must be

```
scanf("%s", player);
```

The user can enter by mistake the following sequence of characters `"yn"` or `"ny"`. This is an invalid answer. Nevertheless your function considers such a string as a valid answer.

The user also can interrupt the input. Logically such a case can be interpreted as the user entered `'n'`. But your function does not process such a case.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be implemented. If the user enters for example an invalid string like "yn", "ny", or "yyy/mm/dd" then the function ignores such an input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int loop_yn( void )
{
    char input[3];

    int answer = 0;

    while ( fgets( input, sizeof( input ), stdin ) != NULL )
    {
        input[0] = toupper( ( unsigned char )input[0] );

        if ( ( input[0] != 'N' && input[0] != 'Y' ) || ( input[1] != '\n' ) )
        {
            printf( "Error: please enter Y or N: " );
            if ( input[0] != '\n' && input[1] != '\n' ) 
            { 
                scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
                scanf( "%*c" );
            }               
        }
        else
        {
            answer = input[0] == 'Y';
            break;
        }
    }

    return answer;
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "Enter Y to continue or N to abort: " );

    loop_yn();

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter Y to continue or N to abort: yy
Error: please enter Y or N: nn
Error: please enter Y or N: 
Error: please enter Y or N: yn
Error: please enter Y or N: yyy/mm/dd
Error: please enter Y or N: nothing
Error: please enter Y or N: y
```

The last user input

```
Error: please enter Y or N: y
```

was valid. All other inputs including the case when the user entered nothing and just pressed the Enter key

```
Error: please enter Y or N:
```

are ignored by the function.